# Error in eclipse while creating table in hbase

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, hbase

```
ERROR client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
```

I'm facing this problem while creating a table in hbase by using java code but my standalone hbase is running well and I'm able to perform all operation on it.

Comment: Can you run jps and give us the output of whats running? Also hbase-site.xml would be helpful.

Comment: Make sure you see hmaster running